# Lots of Login Code

Tags: cakephp-2.0

This is a fairly long question but I have know idea where it's going wrong. I am making an ajax login script using CakePHP 2.0 but it keeps failing. I will post all of my code, and i hope someone has the time to go through it.

**This is my sql Database**

```
AccountID   AccountEmail    AccountPassword  AccountActive  
1   chris@hotmail.co.uk     pass            0   
2   chris@gmail.com         pass            1
```

**This is my relevant Model Code**

```
class Account extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Account';
public $validate = array(
    'AccountEmail' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Please Enter A Valid Email.'
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'rule'    => array('email', true),
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.'
        )
    ),
    'AccountPassword' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Please Enter A Valid Password.'
        )
    )
);  
}
```

**This is my relevant Controller Code**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

/**
* Class Variables
*/
public $helpers = array('Js', 'Html', 'Session', 'Form');
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'RequestHandler',
    'Auth' => array(
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'Accounts', 
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authError' => 'You can\'t Access That Page',
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'AccountEmail', 
                    'password' => 'AccountPassword'
                ),
                'scope' => array('AccountActive' => '1')
            )
        )
    )
);
}

class AccountsController extends AppController {

/**
*   Class Variables 
*/
public $name = 'Accounts';
public $layout = 'Accounts';

/**
*   Class Functions 
*/
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->Account->set($this->data);
        if ($this->Account->validates()) {
            if($this->Auth->login()) {
                echo "logged In";
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "Login Failed";
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'validation/' . json_encode($this->Account->invalidFields());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think there is anything else. Again i'm sorry for the huge amount of code but i just don't know what you need.
The info is all passed via 'echo' to jquery which at the moment is just displaying the response via 'alert'.
I know the validation is working, but if i enter the info of someone who should be able to login it just shows "Login Failed".  Thanks For Your Time.

Answer (score 0):

Your passwords in the database need to be in their hashed form. Using Cake's default settings, '**pass**' would be: **1c31af5bd9913ff511fe780f506e6fab68979b90**