# Login Code Errors

Tags: cakephp-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CakePHP - Login Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331047/cakephp-login-code)

If i am logging a user in with ajax, this is the request jquery sends to the php file,

```
www.site.com?_method=POST&AccountEmail=chris%40gmail.com&AccountPassword=adminpass
```

I think thats what is sends, I open firebug and under 'Post' is lists this as the source,

```
_method=POST&AccountEmail=chris%40gmail.com&AccountPassword=adminpass
```

How can cakephp use this log the user in...?
At the moment i have this code but it is not working.

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->Account->set($this->data);
        if ($this->Account->validates()) {
            if($this->Auth->login()) {
                echo "logged In";
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "Login Failed";
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo 'validation/' . json_encode($this->Account->invalidFields());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Just returns "login failed" even if i send the right user details....

Comment: I assume you've stored that password in it's hashed form in your database?

Comment: Which if you're using the default settings, will be: `d71591452e1a0e33567d31b73340511c90bed01e`

Comment: ah, thought as i hadn't hashed the password in the scripts it didn't need to be in the database...

Comment: Cake does the hashing for you.

Comment: But in the 2.0 cookbook it says i need a beforeSave() to do thehashing

Comment: Yes, when adding a user. But not when *logging in* a user in, which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, if i am putting a hashed password directly in to my database so that i can log in, do i need to do anything with my security salt or cipher seed?

Answer (score 0):

As per your previous question:

Your passwords in the database need to be in their hashed form. Using Cake's default settings, 'pass' would be: **1c31af5bd9913ff511fe780f506e6fab68979b90**